# Feeds - CSV files from directory

Tags: 7, feeds

I am trying to use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to automatically process CSV files in a directory to create nodes.

To help I installed this module ["Feeds Fetcher Directory"](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_fetcher_directory).

I already have the content type built and run into an issue when trying to setup the "Feeds Fetcher Directory".  On the settings page I only have an input for "File mask"
[image]
What is not clear is where I define the directory and what global feeds settings I should use to have it use cron.

When on the "Feeds Fetcher Directory" settings page I get the following error when just trying to click save for the default mask:

> Notice: Undefined index: directory in
>   FeedsFileFetcher->configFormValidate() (line 274 of
>   /home1/theches8/public_html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsFileFetcher.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: allowed_schemes in
>   FeedsFileFetcher->configFormValidate() (line 275 of
>   /xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsFileFetcher.inc).
>   Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   FeedsFileFetcher->configFormValidate() (line 275 of
>   /xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsFileFetcher.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: direct in
>   FeedsFileFetcher->configFormValidate() (line 277 of
>   /xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsFileFetcher.inc).

Please specify an upload directory.

UPDATE:

Based on the feedback from the folks in this forum I tried to install the newest development version of the feeds directory fetcher without success.   I was still unable to determine how to give it a directory that could be space scanned via cron for CSV files import. I did however successfully get my needs met using the core feeds module I was able to just have my back and point to a single CSV file that would be appended to as needed and was consumed the cron.    thanks to everybody on the forum for their help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for a drupal.org module and should be handled in the issue queue there. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2002244

Comment: Having said that, this question is excellently written with all the relevant information so thumbs up for that.

Comment: On your screen shot, did you click on file_scan_directory documentation? Perhaps it tells you there?

Comment: @rooby how do you know this is a bug if he doesn't know how to set this up properly?

Comment: I did click on the file_scan_directory documentation and was unable to determine how it should be applied.   It does reference a as a part of a larger group of variables passed into that method.   Any reason I was hoping to get some help.

Comment: @NoSssweat: Well the error message posted exactly matches the one at https://www.drupal.org/node/2163279 and that issue is closed as a duplicate of the other one I previously linked. I realised after I posted that there was a secondary question however I then found that that question is also answered in the linked ticket (comment #1) so reading that issue should resolve this post. That's just my judgement though, which is why 5 people have to vote to actually put on hold.

Comment: @tavor999: After trying the linked patch and any suggestions in that issue are you still having problems? If so you could edit your question based on any new information and get it reopened.